# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ? Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am stuck and frustrated with the bellow error message:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Medicine\UserBundle\Entity\User
>       ::setUsertype() must be an instance of Medicine\UserBundle\Entity\Usertype, 
>       instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, called in
>       /opt/lampp/htdocs/drugs/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util
>       /PropertyPath.php on line 347 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/drugs/src/
>       Medicine/UserBundle/Entity/User.php line 224

What I think this error is due to use of manytoone field in my entity, I even tried with keeping onetomany in another entity.

I have a user entity and a usertype entity, the usertype_id is a manytoone field in user table. here is the code for both the entities:-

**User**

```
namespace Medicine\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Medicine\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/

class User
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
 protected $username;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Usertype", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usertype_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $usertype;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
 protected $image;

/**
 * Set usertype
 *
 * @param Medicine\UserBundle\Entity\Usertype $usertype
 */
public function setUsertype(\Medicine\UserBundle\Entity\Usertype $usertype)
{
    $this->usertype = $usertype;
}

/**
 * Get usertype
 *
 * @return Medicine\UserBundle\Entity\Usertype 
 */
public function getUsertype()
{
    return $this->usertype;
}
}
```

I am just showing the concerned code, i have all the getter and setter methods for the above code.

**UserType**

```
namespace Medicine\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Medicine\UserBundle\Repository\UsertypeRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="usertype")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/

class Usertype
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $name;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="usertype")
*/
protected $users;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add users
 *
 * @param Medicine\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
*/
public function addUser(\Medicine\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
{
    $this->users[] = $users;
}

/**
 * Get users
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}
}
```

**Controller**

This Executes when a user wants to login. He will fill in the username password and a UserType:

```
public function indexAction()
{
$entity = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(new LoginForm(), $entity);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($entity->getUsertype()); exit;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $userrepository = $em->getRepository('MedicineUserBundle:User');
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($entity->getUsertype()); exit;
        $all = $userrepository->findOneBy(array('login' => $entity->getLogin(), 'password' => $entity->getPassword()));
        if($all)
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MedicineUserBundle_login'));
        }
        }
     }

     return $this->render('MedicineUserBundle:User:loginpage.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

**Login Form**

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('login', 'text', array('label'  => 'Username',))
        ->add('password','password')
    ->add('usertype', 'entity', array('class' => 'MedicineUserBundle:Usertype', 'property'=>'name', 'multiple'  => true, ))

    ;
}
```

Comment: I think the issue lies within your LoginForm - can we see this please?

Comment: @jstephenson :- I Have Updated My Question with the login form as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `'multiple' => true` in combination with your entity association definition is causing this problem.

You should find that if you change multiple to false (and as such can only select one UserType for your User), things work properly.

If you want multiple UserTypes for one User, you have a Many-to-Many association - one user can have many UserTypes, and one UserType can have many Users. See Doctrine's ManyToMany association type to implement this. [Documentation Here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

Hope this helps.