# Symfony 2 Embedded Forms: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Entity::addProperty must be an instance of XX\MyClass, array given

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412961/catchable-fatal-error-argument-1-passed-to-symfony2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579661/catchable-fatal-error-in-form-event-subscriber-using-symfony-2-3) and other ones but no one solved my problem.

I've removed all that I could and narrowed down to one field: adresses.
When I try to follow [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), everything works fine if I follow it, starting from a fresh new project. But when I do it by hand in my other project, I get this error: 
"Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\PersonTeacher::addAdresse() must be an instance of BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Adresse, array given in C:\Users\Olivier\PhpstormProjects\My\My\src\BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\PersonTeacher.php line 111".

Heres the stacktrace:
[image: stacktracke]

Here's my code, where I've remove properties that work:

---

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Controller;

use BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\PersonTeacher;
use BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Adresse;
use BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Form\Type\AdresseType;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function registerTeacherAction(Request $request)
    {
        $person = new PersonTeacher();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($person)
            ->add('adresses', 'collection',
                array(
                    'type' => new AdresseType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                )
            )
        ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /**/
        }
        return $this->render('BNMyBundle:Registration:person_teacher.form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

---

My Entity PersonTeacher:

```
<?php

namespace BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="person_teacher")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Repository\PersonTeacherRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class PersonTeacher extends Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /*--------- snap ---------*/

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(
     *     targetEntity="Adresse",
     *     inversedBy="personsTeacher",
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="person_teacher_adresse")
     **/
    private $adresses;

    /*--------- snap ---------*/

    public function addAdresse(\BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Adresse $adresse) {
        $this->adresses[] = $adresse;
        return $this;
    }
    public function removeAdresse(\BN\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Adresse $adresse) {
        $this->adresses->removeElement($adresse);
    }
    public function getAdresses() {
        return $this->adresses;
    }
    /*--------- snap ---------*/
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->adresses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

---

Hints

NB: I've checked that the form is properly sent, that the information are properly formatted, and I've done step by step debugging with xdebug, but it's too complex for me (yet) to see what I am missing.

It's a problem with the `'collection'` type: if I remove `'by_reference' => false`, then it works.... only if I do not persist it.

If I try to persist it with this code:

```
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $person=$form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($person);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Then I get this error:

Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in (projectpath)\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1572

Why?

Comment: What if you change your `ManyToMany` to a `OneToMany` as a test?

Comment: I've tried to change with another `ManyToMany` relation: lessons (one teacher may give one or more lesson and one lesson may be given by one or more teacher). It works. So the only explanation is that there are some fields or one declaration missing, but I really dont know what could be missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found it.

The problem was in my `FormType` `AddressType.php` file: the function `setDefaultOptions()` was missing. Everything was okay, but this function ir **mandatory** if you want doctrine to be able to convert the incoming fields into a specific class.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(
    \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Adresse',
    ));
}
```

I'm quite angry about the time I've lost with that. You have to know by heart the whole symfony 2 process to solve quickly those kind of problems, or it will take 6 hours like it did to me. Symfony 2 itself is a whole [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html): you feel like gaining time but you dont. Symfony is supposed to simplify your life, but in the end, to quote Joël Spolsky:

> It's a leaky abstraction: it means that abstractions do not really
>   simplify our lives as much as they were meant to.
>   Code generation tools which pretend to abstract out something, like
>   all abstractions, leak, and the only way to deal with the leaks
>   competently is to learn about how the abstractions work and what they
>   are abstracting.

Comment: I saved yours, but lost one **`:^/`**